# Can we trigger Azure Logic App on demand?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

can I trigger a Logic app on demand?? 
My requirement is, I am creating an application which will export data from CRM to Redis cache so I want to trigger my logic app on demand.

PS: I am new in Logic Apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could add `Schedule` Trigger to your logic app. You could refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-recurrence), there are detailed description about how to set the recurrence.

Recurrence schedules support interval time,start time, on these days etc settings.

If you still have other questions, please let me know.